# Thymeleaf th:each access parameter in loop

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to superscript a number in a html-table which will be displayed in an E-Mail.

my code so far is the following:

```
<th:block th:each="param, rowStat: ${someList}">
    <th style="..." th:utext="#{some.translation(${param}, ${rowStat.count})}">superscript</th>
</th:block>
```

"someList" is a simple list of strings and "some.translation" is the following:

```
{0} (moreInfo)<sup>{1}</sup>
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like:

String1 (moreInfo)<sup>1</sup>
String2 (moreInfo)<sup>2</sup>

My problem is a thymeleaf exception saying that the access to variable "param" is forbidden in this context. Accessing "rowStat.count" is working fine.

If there is a simpler way to display a superscript number it would also be fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `param` is not allowed, because that is a reserved word for Thymeleaf, for retrieving request parameters. Try changing it to something else:

```
<th:block th:each="myParam, rowStat: ${someList}">
    <th style="..." th:utext="#{some.translation(${myParam}, ${rowStat.count})}">superscript</th>
</th:block>
```

See also the Thymeleaf documentation here: [Request parameters](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.).

> ***`param`** : for retrieving request parameters. `${param.foo}` is a `String[]` with the values of the `foo` request parameter, so `${param.foo[0]}` will normally be used for getting the first value.*

Comment: Oh my lord, that really was all I had to do. In a different context it worked with "param" but I guess I was just lucky there.

Thank you!